# Magento2 - where the admin console user preferences stored?

Tags: admin, session, magento2.1.5, product-grid

I have logged into the admin panel of Magento 2, gone to products->catalog and have set the 'per page' limit to 900.

My Magento instance can't return 900 records in one page so it crashes, and a div with a spinner remains active after an error message appears saying 'Attention: Something went wrong' - so I can't revise the 900 to a more suitable number.

I've tried clearing cache/client cookies, etc - but nothing is happening.  I can't seem to find where the catalog product grid limit value is being stored.

Please if someone can assist, it would be good.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your grid preference is saved in bookmark table

Go to your database and find **ui_bookmark** table

find the namespace entry with **product_listing** and remove current or both current and default. Don't worry magento will generate the default again runtime

Comment: Thanks @userpk - I edited the record and now it's working; that's the only table I didn't look in :)